# Add query string to all Media item in Sitecore SXA 9.3

Tags: sxa, media-library, link-manager, mediaurls

Is there any way by which I can add a query string in each media item requested in SXA include CSS, js, images, fonts, etc.

Current URL  - http://us.dev.local/-/media/base-themes/core-libraries/scripts/ie-origin-fix.js
Required URL - http://us.dev.local/-/media/base-themes/core-libraries/scripts/ie-origin-fix.js?sc=1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a custom `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider`.
For example

```
public class MediaProvider : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider
{

    public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)
    {
        var url = base.GetMediaUrl(item, options);

        url = WebUtil.AddQueryString(url, "sc", "1");

        return url;
    }

}
```

Config patch

```
<mediaLibrary>
    <mediaProvider 
        type="Yours"
        patch:instead="mediaProvider[@type='Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
</mediaLibrary>
```